# Android Studio stack=java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/icu/util/Calendar;

Tags: java, android, calendar, alarmmanager

I have used the `calendar` class for a alarm app with the `alarm manager`, but I have an error with the instance of the class `calendar`.
I have investigated in other forums but I haven't find the proper solutions.
please I need your help.

### the error is marked in the instance of the calendar class

[image: the error is marked in the instance of the calendar class]

[image]

Answer (score 20):

As far as i can see, you could just use the normal [Calendar](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) instead of the in API 24 introduced [ICU Calendar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/util/Calendar.html). Try to use this import `java.util.Calendar` instead of this import `android.icu.util.Calendar`.

Comment: Well I used  android.icu.util.Calendar and when I changed to android.util.Calendar the error disappeared

Comment: this answer saved me 1 hour of stress haha

Answer (score 2):

From Calendar pick date:
`import java.util.Calendar` instead of this `import android.icu.util.Calendar`
And Then write those code code for Date Pick.

```
Calendar callForDate = Calendar.getInstance();

java.text.SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy");

final String saveCurrentDate = currentDate.format(callForDate.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, changed the import from android.icu.util.Calendar to java.util.Calendar and it work! hope it helps you!